# How do you get interpolated data points in Core Plot?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

In Core Plot, as the user scrolls, I am trying to move an annotation along the line of a scatter plot. I have data points at each hour, but would like to plot the annotation at more than just the hour marks. I'd like to get CGPoint information for interpolated data. For instance, I'd like to get the CGPoint for hour (index) 12.25.

I have been searching for ways to do this, but can't find one.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want a point between two points given a certain parameter(hour)?

Comment: Yep. I gave Y values for points at index 12 and 13, core plot then interpolated datapoints in between 12 and 13. I'd like to know what the interpolated Y value is at, say, 12.25. And I'd like to get a CGPoint from that, so I could create an annotation anchored there.

Comment: Essentially, I want this method on CPTScatterPlot to accept a CGFloat -(CGPoint)plotAreaPointOfVisiblePointAtIndex:(NSUInteger)idx;

Comment: Keep in mind what you are doing to the user by using a computed interpolation value. It's presented as ultimate value while it is rather an educated guess, so you are "lying" to the user (as Edward Tufte has explained it). As a general rule: keep the "lying factor" of your data display as low as possible.

Comment: http://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/books_vdqi

Comment: Thanks, Mike. For the graph I'm making, it's OK to "lie".

Answer (score 0):

[Linear Interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) (Wikipedia link) is easy.

Given two points, `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)`, a point between them where `a` is a fraction between zero (0) and one (1), the interpolated point `(x, y)` is given by:

```
x = (1 - a) * x1 + a * x2
y = (1 - a) * y1 + a * y2
```

In the example given in the question, `a` would be 0.25.

Comment: Hey Eric -- I don't think I was clear at all in my question. I am referring specifically to core plot. Core plot lets you do a curve interpolation (spline maybe?) for your graph. I am looking for a core plot method that lets me access their interpolated values. I do not want to calculate my own interpolated points.

Comment: Core Plot uses the Core Graphics function `CGPathAddCurveToPoint()` to draw cubic Bézier curves between the points when using `CPTScatterPlotInterpolationCurved`. I'm not sure how much work it would be to expose a method to do the interpolation for you. Open a feature request on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues).

Comment: Thanks, Eric. Yeah, I tried a few different options. I did a spline interpolation, but I think I'm not guaranteed to get the same Y values as the curve. Then I tried doing a spline interpolation with 60 points between real data points, and turning Core Plot's off. It displayed pretty poorly (pixelated, choppy). So I tried both at once, but of course there are massive performance issues.